# how can I enable the condition compilation symbol in the sample level?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have created new conditional compilation symbol in like NO_DESIGNER_SERIALZE to decide serialization visibility is content or hidden in my source library. The code is like below,

Code snippet :

```
#if NO_DESIGNER_SERIALIZE
[DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] 
#else
[DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)] 
#endif
```

I have two different samples, for one sample I need to use the serialization visibility to content. And another one sample, I need to avoid serialization, so I need to enable the serialization visibility to hidden. But both samples need to use the same assembly which is created by using above code. How can I enable or disable the serialization by using conditional compilation symbol is samples?

And this serialization of properties will be occurs in design time, so that only I am using the conditional compilation symbols instead of boolean variables. So How can i enable the conditional compilation in both samples?

Comment: Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx

Comment: I have already declared and used the conditional compilation symbol in my library. But I don't know how to use this in sample level. I have two samples, but both are using same assembly which is created with conditional compilation. In one sample I need to enable the conditional compilation symbol to enable the designerserializationvisibility.hidden to avoid serialization. And another sample, I need to disable the conditional compilation symbol to enable the designerserializationvisibility to content to serialize the contents. so how  can i use the conditional compilation to achieve this?